# Proving that a function is either Big Oh or Big Omega for all functions

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation, asymptotics

Trying to prove that there exists a function f from natural numbers to positive real numbers, such that for every function g from natural numbers to nonnegative real numbers, g is either the big-oh of f or big-omega of f.

I have attempted to prove this through proof by contradiction but I'm having trouble generating a contradiction to show that for all functions f, there is a function g that is neither the big-oh or big-omega of f. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: For any $f$ define $g(n)$ to be $0$ if $n$ is odd, and $\max(n,nf(n))$ if $n$ is even. Then $g$ is neither a big-$O$ nor a big-$\Omega$ of $f$.

Comment: Do you think such an $f$ exists? Or are you trying to prove that it cannot exist?

Comment: For any such $f$, you can construct $g$ so that $f/g$ and $g/f$ are both unbounded...

Comment: @CaptainLama You should submit your comment as an answer